# Is there a way to turn firefox to "tablet mode" on 2in1 device?

Tags: windows-10, firefox

I'm using firefox on Lenovo Yoga laptop with touch-screen. My OS is Windows 10. I would like to turn firefox to some kind of "tablet mode" every time when my OS is switched to tablet mode. When I'm talking about tablet mode, I mean:

- bigger icons in firefox toolbars
- sending different device info to web servers in order to receive tablet-optimized web pages if present

Is something like that possible? Is there some addon for it? Or is it possible only with some other browser?

Comment: Firefox doesn't have a tablet mode.  The developers were working on one, many years ago, they discontinued any plans for it shortly there after.

Comment: Your only bet might be Microsoft Edge

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use Comodo IceDragon browser, which is based on firefox and it have tablet mode.